# What should I do with this Ficus elastica (Rubber fig)?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, houseplants, roots, figs

Something is wrong with my Ficus elastica (Rubber fig).

What is this white hard salt-like thing?  It is on the backside of some leaves. I cleaned this with water and cotton and it came off, but it was somewhat hard. Is it sap? Is it the thing which helps in rubber production? If yes, can I make an eraser with it?

[image]

Should I cut the aerial roots? would that be good or bad for the plant?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi 4-K! I love your new profile picture-very cool! When you ask a question, would you mind putting the name of the plant in it, even though you already have it in the title? It helps because people often read both separately, and that way all the information is in all the places! Thanks!

Comment: @Sue Thanks! :) I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's a crack in that leaf which has oozed sap which has then dried. Quite why there's a crack I don't know, could just be physical damage, but check the backs of leaves thoroughly, along with the stems and trunk to see if there's any scale insect present.  And no, you can't make a rubber with it!

Comment: What about the aerial roots? Can I cut them or just leave them be? Will that cause any problem to the plant? :)

Comment: Cut them off.  Those are great in the larger ecosystem of a garden but otherwise they are just more to maintain for the plant with nothing in return.  No stumps left.  Clean your shears with alcohol first.